# Validation in vue js using vee-validate having error

Tags: vue.js

I want give the validation in vuejs for that i am using vee-validate

- My vue js version is 2.6.10
- And install run -npm install vee-validate

**I declare in main.ts:**

```
import  VeeValidate  from "vee-validate";
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
```

**But having error**:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'VeeValidate') was not found in 'vee-validate'

**And also on console:**

> Cannot read property 'install' of undefined
>       at Function.Vue.use

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this seems to happen in any version after 3.0. I installed vee-validate@2.2.15 and it worked.

Answer (score 21):

```
import * as VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
```

that resolve the problem

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. It has solved my problem.Thanks

Comment: You should make use of tree shaking to remove redundant imports at compile time by using object destructuring syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Since the newsest release, it's name had changed, now if you want to call it, and you register it :

```
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';

// Register it globally
// main.js or any entry file.
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
```

Of course, you can check the Npm package documentation on : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate

Answer (score 0):

To install it, Run

```
npm i vee-validate --save
```