# VueJs + Vee Validate@2 "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

When trying to get form data I am getting the following error in console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
at _callee$ (AddProduct.vue?eb76:67)
at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
at VueComponent.addProduct (AddProduct.vue?eb76:67)
```

My VueJs component :  https://pastebin.com/9v2bsEaP

It emits and event that is called from AppVue.
This is it:
https://pastebin.com/FrNzzCn4

I suspect this is caused by validation but I cannot figure out what I miss. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your vee validate isn't instantiated properly. Please if you can read this article: [Validation in vue js using vee-validate having error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674453/validation-in-vue-js-using-vee-validate-having-error) it may help you in the correct direciton.

I checked your code and cant see the import statement as mentioned in the last answer posted in that thread.

Comment: It is imported in main.js like : import  VeeValidate  from "vee-validate";
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

Comment: you need to import it like so ```import * as VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not change the error message. Thanks for looking, anyway.